# Could not retrieve the repositories: Visual Studio Team Services and Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to do [Continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Team Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/). But when i try to connect Azure my web app to Visual Studio Team Services (Visual Studio Online) after typing the url for Team Services. it does the authorization successfully. but I get the following error.

[image]

I was looking at this screen for a long time but it doesn't seem to complete.
What mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce that issue with azure classic portal too. But you can achieve that with new azure portal.

Simple steps:

1. Log on [new azure portal](https://portal.azure.com).
2. [Link or create VSTS account](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs).
3. Create new Web app in azure.
4. Click that web app in App Services list
5. Click Deployment option in App Deployment section=>Click Choose Source 
   [image]
6. Choose account, project and branch
   [image]

After success configure that, it will deploy your project to the web app. If you can change code in corresponding project, then commit and push to the server, it will redeploy to the web app.